# HTML Tags working in local. But are missing on server in angular

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular-cli

In angular, I got an issue where in my code is working fine on local. But on server side HTML Tags are missing.
I called an (get)api. I was getting CORS error. Which I solved making proxy server. 
https://medium.com/better-programming/setup-a-proxy-for-api-calls-for-your-angular-cli-app-6566c02a8c4d

In ts after button click. A function is been called submitform()
I had written api calling function.

I binded with following html component.

Disclaimer: {{accuracy}}

I am able to see div in localhost. But not able to see div on server. 
I tried console.logs and alerts. But both of them didn't appeared on server url.

Cmd used to build: ng build --prod

Comment: You do realize that a proxy doesn’t work for a prod build right?

Comment: Is there a method where in I can pass through build and not get Cors errors. I am also using custom header in post

Comment: You need to configure CORS in your back end. The configuration depends on the programming language you're using on the back-end, but you basically have to accept any HTTP OPTIONS request (OPTION is an HTTP method, like GET, PUT, etc) and, in the answer to an OPTIONS request, authorize explicitly the requests from specific origins (localhost, specific IPs, URLs, etc) in the header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`. If you set it to `*` in the server, you'll probably get rid of CORS. Most backend frameworks (Spring, Express, .Net) have some features to automatically do that for you.

Comment: Take a good read at this article: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS